# Existence of solutions to sytems of 1st order ODE (Nonhomogenious system)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading an article based on resolution of a systems of first-order differential equations, and I have to provide a proof of in my M.Sc. thesis:

In this article, I have found a results that doesn't convince me, because the have written:

$$M^{-1}v'_1(t)+v_1(t) = g_1(t), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ where $M^{-1}$ is the inverse of the matrix $M$.

So, the article directly concludes that the solution of the equation is unique and is given by:

$$v_1(s)e^{-M(t-\sigma )}+ \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{-M(t-s )}ds$$

But, when I try to prove it, I find the following result:

By multiplying the system $(1)$ by the matrix $M$, we have:

\begin{align*}
M^{-1}Mv'_1(t)+Mv_1(t) &= Mg_1(t)\\
\Longrightarrow v'_1(t)+Mv_1(t) &= Mg_1(t)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
v'_1(t)e^{Mt}+Mv_1(t)e^{Mt} &= Mg_1(t)e^{Mt}\\
\Longrightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg[ v_1(t)e^{Mt}\Bigg] &= Mg_1(t)e^{Mt}\\
\Longrightarrow \int_{\sigma}^{t} \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg[ v_1(t)e^{Mt}\Bigg] dt &= M \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{Ms}ds\\
\Longrightarrow v_1(t)e^{Mt}|^t_{\sigma} &= M \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{Ms}ds\\
v_1(t)e^{Mt}-v_1(\sigma)e^{M\sigma} &= M \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{Ms}ds\\
v_1(t)e^{Mt} &= v_1(\sigma)e^{M\sigma}+M \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{Ms}ds\\
v_1(t) &= v_1(s)e^{-M(t-\sigma)}+M \int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{-M(t-s )}ds
\end{align*}

**Question**: ***Why did the author omit the matrix $M$ in their result?*** Because I don't see where I have made a mistake. In their solution there is no matrix $M$ before the integral $\displaystyle{\int_{\sigma}^{t} g_1(s)e^{-M(t-s)}ds}$

***Thank you at advance for your help.***